# Need help with strange scaling behavior on my torso model; following a blender video

Tags: scale

I am brand new, and I am following a blender video by Sebastian Lague, and I just want to figure out why i am not able to properly scale the selected edge of my torso model, as he does in the video.

> [The vertices / edge i have selected before
>   scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7cqB.jpg) (I use alt+right-click or
>   alt+shift+right-click, just as in the video)
>
> [What the issue looks likes when i try to scale it with the S or alt-S
>   hotkeys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGilX.jpg)
>
> [What it should look like](https://youtu.be/aAO4C_8y0w8?t=4m5s)

What the heck is going on? If this isn't normal behavior, I seem to have accidentally created double vertices at the same points or something? If this behavior is normal, i must not be selecting the edge / vertices properly?

Thanks in advance and happy holidays!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a different number of loop cuts than the example - were you embellishing the design, or had you made some errors in following the example?  From my own experiences, making errors and then correcting them during a tutorial led to some weird results and it was a while before I learnt to `remove duplicates`.

To check your theory about double vertices, select your entire mesh (`A` followed by `A` again should do the trick from the view in the images) and then select `remove duplicates` from your left hand menu. Off the top of my head, I can't remember if it is `T` or `N` to display this menu from the view that you have in your images - one will bring up the right properties menu and the other will bring up the left menu options.

Are you also trying to scale along the right axes? `S`-`Y` will ensure it is locked on the y-axis as noted in the video. Selecting `Shift-Y` instead of `Y` will result in the scaling happening along the X- and Z-axes. Can't judge from your static screen shots.

Comment: Yes!! Removed duplicates worked!


To answer your first question, yes, i thought i should be able to slightly change the design to make it my own.


I did seem to create additional vertices some how? If you have any ideas on why that occured, i would love to hear it so as to avoid this in the future.

Comment: I have a follow-up question. I wonder if the vertices aren't.. "connected"?... Because i removed the duplicates maybe? Perhaps that Is something that i don't need to worry about?..

Comment: Creating additional loops, and not moving them, will create additional vertices. And because they are on top of each other, not easy to see.  Easy to do when a beginner. Removing duplicate vertices will not disconnect the remaining ones.